# Sql INNER JOIN is not working propertly and how do i show uploaded files on the html form using Jquery/Ajax

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax

I want to get results from 2 table using SQL INNER JOIN but it's only showing 1st result not others one. If i select other data then it's showing following error message:

> Warning: Invalid argument supplied for foreach() in **D:\software installed\xampp\htdocs\contact-management\getContactDetails.php** on line **14**
> []

Description of my functionality:

I have 2 table in my database.

1. **contact_details**:

   ```
   cdid, family_name, given_name, work_phone, mobile_phone, email, email_private, cid
   ```
2. **contact_docs**:

   ```
   docid, cdid, file_name, file_des
   ```

I'm showing all **contacts** (only family_name) from database. After select each **contacts** then it's showing/loading all contact details using Jquery/ajax which is showing on a **HTML FORM**. So now it's showing contact_details data on the html input type = text field. But  I also need show contact_docs data which is actually **files**.

So when I send a request to the server using jQuery/ajax I've to use SQL inner join query to get the result from both table based on `id (cdid)`. But unfortunately my inner join query is not working properly. It's not showing all contact details data on the html form if I select different **contacts**. Only showing 1st result.

My questions are:

1. How do I fix this inner join query?
2. How do I show the uploaded file on the form (file link would be better) when whole form is load with all data from 2 table ?

**Note:** I can successfully edit/insert the data to database but issue about showing the data with file.

This is my code:

**Html** page:

```
<div id="showContactsDetails">
<h2>Individual Record Details</h2>
    <div style=" visibility:hidden;" id="visiable">    
    <span class="mandatory"><sub>* Required</sub></span>
    <!--success update -->  
    <div id="success"></div>

<form action="" method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data" id="all_contact_details">
<table width="450" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">  
  <input type="hidden" name="cdid" id="cdid"/>
  </tr>     
<tr>
    <td>Company Name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="company_name" id="company_name" disabled="disabled"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Family name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="family_name" id="family_name"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Given name</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="given_name" id="given_name"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Work Phone</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="work_phone" id="work_phone"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Mobile Phone</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="mobile_phone" id="mobile_phone"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Email address</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email" id="email"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Private email address</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="email_private" id="email_private"/></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>Upload your document</td>
    <td><input type="text" name="file_des_1" id="file_des1" placeholder="short description of your document" class="shor"/><span class="mandatory"><sup>*</sup></span></td>
  <tr>
    <td></td>  
    <td align="left"><input name="file1" type="file" id="file" class="file"/></td>
    <span class="file_des_1"></span>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="file_des_2" id="file_des2" placeholder="short description of your document" class="shor"/><span class="mandatory"><sup>*</sup></span></td>
  <tr>
    <td></td>  
    <td align="left"><input type="file" name="file2" id="file_2" class="file"/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="file_des_3" id="file_des3" placeholder="short description of your document" class="shor"/><span class="mandatory"><sup>*</sup></span></td>
  <tr>
    <td></td>  
    <td align="left"><input type="file"  name="file3" id="file_3" class="file"/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td></td>
    <td><input type="text" name="file_des_4" id="file_des4" placeholder="short description of your document" class="shor"/><span class="mandatory"><sup>*</sup></span></td>
  <tr>
    <td></td>  
    <td align="left"><input type="file"  name="file4" id="file_4" class="file"/></td>
  </tr>

  <tr>
    <td>&nbsp;</td>
    <td><input type="button" name="submit" value="Update Details" class="submit" id="upload"/></td>
  </tr>  
</table>
</form> 
</div> 
</div><!--showContactsDetails-->
```

jQuery/Ajax page:

```
//edit the form....................
<script>
$('body').on('click', '#upload', function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    var formData = new FormData($(this).parents('form')[0]);


    $.ajax({
        url: 'editContactDetails.php',
        type: 'POST',
        xhr: function() {
            var myXhr = $.ajaxSettings.xhr();
            return myXhr;
        },
        success: function(data){                    
            $("#success").html(data);
            document.getElementById("all_contact_details").reset();


        },
        data: formData,
        cache: false,
        contentType: false,
        processData: false
    });
});    

//load the html form with all contact details..................................................
function getDetails(id) {
        id = id;        
        $.ajax({        
                url: 'getContactDetails.php',
                type: 'post',             
                data: {'id' : id},
                dataType : 'json',
                success: function( res ) {
                    document.getElementById("visiable").style.visibility = "visible";
                    console.log(res);
                    $.each( res, function( key, value ) {
                        console.log(key, value);
                        $('input[type=text][name='+key+']').val(value);
                        $('input[type=hidden][name='+key+']').val(value);
                        $('textarea[name='+key+']').val(value);

                    });

                }            
        });
    }


</script>
```

Php page (getContactDetails.php):

```
<?php
ob_start();
require_once("config.php");
$id  = (int) $_POST['id'];

$sql = mysql_query("SELECT contact_details.cdid, contact_details.family_name, contact_docs.file_name FROM contact_details INNER JOIN contact_docs ON contact_details.cdid = contact_docs.cdid WHERE contact_docs.cdid = '$id'");

$res =  mysql_fetch_array($sql);
$data = array();
foreach( $res as $key => $value ) { 
    $data[$key] = $value;   
}
echo json_encode($data);
?>
```

I'm a new in web development field. So may be my code is wrong that's why your help is greatly appreciated :)

Comment: Condition `WHERE contact_docs.cdid = '$id'` means that you receive only one row per query (assuming `id` is unique).

Comment: No when I select each contact I'm getting different `id` using jquery/ajax from db and it's Unique.

Comment: @Strawberry after echo it's showing `Resource id #5{"0":"16","cdid":"16","1":"newfsdfdsfdf","family_name":"newfsdfdsfdf","2":"fc42c3fdf694b196d86fb39ba93ff849.xls","file_name":"fc42c3fdf694b196d86fb39ba93ff849.xls"}`

Comment: Anyway, it kind of looks like it's working !?!?!

Comment: try die function to check query error if any, mysql_query(query) or die(mysql_error());

Comment: when i select first contact then `sql` working but when i select second or later contact then its showing same error.

Comment: you error is $data[$key] replace with $data[$key][]

Comment: @Kate I'm trying with this.

Comment: @Kate showing same error.

Answer (score 0):

I think you want something like this... (using deprecated API)

```
<?php
require_once("config.php");

$id  = (int) $_GET['id'];

$query = "
"SELECT c.cdid
      , c.family_name
      , d.file_name 
   FROM contact_details c
   JOIN contact_docs d 
     ON c.cdid = d.cdid 
  WHERE d.cdid = $id
";

$result = mysql_query($query);

$data = array();

while ($res =  mysql_fetch_array($result)){
foreach( $res as $key => $value ) {
    $data[$key][] = $value;
}
}
echo json_encode($data);   

?>
```

Comment: Without `INNER JOIN` it's working perfectly for input type=text part. But I also need to show other table (contact_docs) files based on cdid so It's need `INNER JOIN`.

Comment: is there any solutions ?

Comment: I wrote the error message when I post the question. Please check it.

Comment: Ok I'm trying with this.

Comment: Yes. now it's not showing the error message but it doesn't showing the data on the html form e.g. Family name.

Comment: In console log I just see third bracket `[]`

Comment: I don't think so. It's running the sql and foreach() successfully. But why it's not showing the data on the form ! Strange !

Comment: Oh, I changed to GET for testing - did you change back to POST?

Comment: It would be useful to see proper DDLs and the desired result (and subsequent json string)

Comment: do you want to see it on live server ?

Comment: Mmm, not really. Paste it here, and/or stick it on sqlfiddle

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/55274/discussion-between-babu-and-strawberry).

Comment: Here's fine - just delete previous correspondence